# Re-index sorted series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of ints, which is unsorted and is indexed 1..2000. If I sort this series, then the values become sorted but they keep their old indices (which makes sense). My question is, how can I re-index this series, so 1 is the index of the smallest value, 2 is that of the 2nd smallest and so on?

To illustrate, my starting series (length 4 for simplicity):

```
0: 500
1: 249
2: 873
3: 90
```

sorting makes:

```
3: 90
1: 249
0: 500
2: 873
```

How can I make the above into

```
0: 90
1: 249
2: 500
3: 873
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by calling to `reset_index()`

```
s.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

More about it in [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)

> inplace : boolean, default False Modify the Series in place (do not
>   create a new object)
>
> drop : boolean, default False Do not try to insert index into
>   dataframe columns

The inplace parameter affect the result only when `drop=True` and the result stays as series.

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame`

Comment: @Bluefire , You're right, you should add `drop=True` as a parameter.

Comment: `>>> type(series.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True))`
`NoneType`

Comment: @Bluefire , That's right as inplace modify the series in place, it shouldn't create an new object.

Comment: @Bluefire , If you use s.reset_index(), you will see that you create new object.